# How much Data I can save through Electron in my local database?

Tags: javascript, electron, nosql

I need to store data in LOCAL STORAGE in electron. 
- Working offline for Desktop App ?
- How much limit of Data I can store locally ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values

Comment: Yep, somehow it's helpful to understand browser cache storage.

I need to know that how we can get more storage for Electron Desktop App ?

We can use [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) but how we store locally ?